# C# make a program run its self but able to run code on it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a program that if a person selects more than 1 thing, it opens another version of its self. I made a function that I need to run on the second one from the first one. And this is what I have so far, but I realized that I couldn't run code on it, so I wondered if there was a way to do that?

```
var app = Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
if (location.EndsWith(@"\"))
{
    //app.open(location + item);
}
else
{
    //app.Open(location + @"\" + item);
}
```

Comment: Google for "C# single instance application"

Comment: Do you want pass `item` to another program instance? What is `item` - complex type or something like simple number or string?

Comment: One of the simpler ways is to reference the VB.NET helpers; they have built in functionality for launching one instance of an application and if another instance is launched it can pass its arguments to the first instance and quit. This means you can select 50 files in explorer, right click and choose "open with YOURAPP", the 50 copies of your app will launch, 49 of them will send the arguments they were started with (one filename) to the first instance, and then they quit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/tyler_whitney/single-instance-applications-and-c

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I am kind of new to asking questions on stack overflow, so I think this is how I reply to you. And it is a string, and yes, I want to pass it to another program instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it command line arguments, use the second argument in `Process.Start`

```
var app = Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, "/" + item);
```

Then you can read them from the `args` parameter in the `Program.Main` method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
}
```